# Compare rows from 2 worksheets and update a specific column

Tags: excel, vba

Please see attached picture.

Workbook 1 is the end product of merging, comparing, formatting, and calculating datasets from a couple of sources. At the beginning of each month, one of the sources gets a staffing update. While this update is running, the [image]data represented in Column O will contain 0's. The process takes several hours, but data is updated in this workbook each hour.

What I need to achieve is running a report **after** the staffing update is completed (represented by Workbook 2) and comparing the data in Workbook 2 to Workbook 1. If ***ALL*** data in each row matches between the two workbooks, except for Column O, then Column O needs to get updated from Workbook 2. I should note that the data in the two workbooks will be identical except in column O.

I have looked at other questions/answers on other forums and here in SO, but cannot find anything that matches what I need. If there is an answer out there that matches my requirements, please comment me the link.

Comment: Hmm this has been asked numerous times on SO. Not sure if it was ever answered fully...

Comment: You will need to use the Range.Find method to find the correct row then iterate through the columns testing the values.  If all are equal then use the value.

Comment: @ScottCraner is that really best architecture? I am with Karl below. Wouldn't it be easier to concat everything then compare? Edit: hmm I guess to concat, you still have to loop columns XD Otherwise, it's an array then you'd have to loop array which I guess is technically faster but not easier XD

Comment: @findwindow either way if the rows do not line up then loops are involved, either find the correct row first or loop twice trough an array, which now that I think of it may be faster.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by finding correct row. We need to test all rows? But yea, loops are unavoidable.

Comment: @findwindow Range.Find and Range.FindNext will loop through only those rows that the SKUs match, thus cutting out many unneeded loops.

Comment: I must've misunderstood the question.

Comment: I don't think it is a one for one placement, as in I do not think the rows are in order.  If so then yes loading the whole into an array and looping through each row and each column would be the quickest. @findwindow

Comment: @findwindow I have updated the question with information that I hope clarifies what I need. All I really need to do is update the data in column O where all the data in the rest of the row matches between each workbook. If column ) in workbook 2 is >0 and column O in workbook 1 <> column O of workbook 2, then the value in workbook 2 column O needs to be copied to Column O in workbook 1.

Comment: Ok, that's my understanding. So yea, I would array each row and loop that for the test.

Comment: @ScottCraner You are correct, the rows will not always match up in their order between the 2 workbooks, that is what makes this tricky. Otherwise, I would just manually copy and paste. The number of rows is always growing.

Comment: Ooooohhh. Now I get it. Edit: yea, so do what Scott says.

Comment: I foresee lots of loops in your future.  That is as far as my crystal ball will take me today.

Comment: What about my future?? @ScottCraner

Comment: @ScottCraner Great! More loops. Great! More loops. Great! More loops. Great! More loops. Great! More loops. Great! More loops. Great! More loops. Great! More loops. Great! More loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all the rows except for Row O and put them in a long string, that is (concatenate them in a line) and use an IF THEN statement comparing the differences.  If a difference is found between the rows, you can then update them with the value of Column O from Workbook 2.

Comment: As pointed out in the question, I know where the difference is and need to copy that difference from workbook 2 to workbook B, but only if all other columns in that row match.

Comment: Concatenating the rows should still work, just leave out the one row (Column O) you know is wrong, then make the compare.  Your question sounded like it wanted a broad solution.  Let me know if I'm not completely understanding your question, if there is some other way I can help.  Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your answer so I can change the down-vote. I think I jumped the gun because I misunderstood what you meant. Please explain further what you mean by concatenating the rows.